# Sorting algorithm by average score

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting

See example data input below. (MSSQL is target system) There are values 1-14 (as example, target range is 1-300aprox). Each value have its own score.

The goal is to sort the values by average score. Average score of dataset below is 16.

Now, what my idea is - the sorting algorithm should first divide the dataset by score then the first lookup would be - 1. Searching, it should try to find out ID with SCORE 16- > ID 1. Second lookup would be - cumulative AVERAGE score is 16*2(number of lookup) = 32. Score so far is 10 (ID1 = score 10). That means difference is 22, so i am looking for value 22- (22 and lower) but also lowest possible. In this example its first ID with SCORE 20. ID2 etc. Is that description understandable? Do you see any other possibility to do the sorting? Target language is T-SQL.

```
ID    | SCORE
----- | ----- 
1     |     10
2     |     20
3     |     10
4     |     10
5     |     10
6     |     20
7     |     20
8     |     30
9     |     10
10    |     25
11    |     20
12    |     30
13    |     10
14    |     10
```

Comment: This looks complicated. It may be solvable with some recursive query; I don't know. I would simply write a program and use a programming language for this I guess.

Comment: Help us help you. Edit your question to include desired results.